# Save record of model is not working in ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What I have done -

Model -

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
   book_name: DS.attr('string'),
   edition: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Router -

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('books', function() {
      this.route('new');
   });
});


App.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('book');
    },

    actions: {
       save: function() {
          this.modelFor('newBook').save();
       }
    }
});
```

Now Can anybody help me.. How to save data ?

I am getting error like

```
TypeError: this.modelFor(...) is undefined
this.modelFor('newBook').save();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how the context of your action looks like.

But one option is to pass the object you want to save as a parameter like this `{{action save myBook}}`.

Then you action could look like this:

```
App.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('book');
    },

    actions: {
       save: function(book) {
          book.save();
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
App.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('book');
    },

    actions: {
       save: function() {
          this.get('model').save();  
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this code also. but it shows error like
TypeError: this.get(...).save is not a function